# Power BI - Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060

Tags: mongodb, powerbi

I'm getting this error message randomly on the power bi connector for MongoDB atlas.

```
Last refresh failed: Mon Jan 25 2021 10:49:32 GMT+0800 (Malaysia Time)
Unable to connect to the data source undefined.Hide details
Underlying error code:  -2147467259
Underlying error message:   ODBC: ERROR [08S01] [MySQL][ODBC 1.4(w) Driver]Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet', system error: 10060
DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult:   -2147467259
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourceKind:    Odbc
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.DataSourcePath:    dsn=xxxxx
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.OdbcErrors:    #table({"SQLState", "NativeError", "Message"}, {})
Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason:    DataSource.Error
Cluster URI:    WABI-SOUTH-EAST-ASIA-B-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Activity ID:    ed9699bb-ba27-4383-a92b-648b9e611092
Request ID: bfe69bee-f7c2-47f4-ff41-b1aba34311ef
Time:   2021-01-25 02:49:32Z
```

Comment: Did you end up resolving this issue? I am facing the same problem

Comment: so far no solutions

Comment: We ended up updating our cluster to a more powerful machine and ensuring that updates are not occuring at the same time and the problem seems to have subsided

Answer (score 0):

**Environment**

```
Tableau Desktop
Windows
MongoDB BI Connector
```

**Resolution**

Work with your MongoDB administrator to correctly define the MongoDB database server location in the MongoDB connection URI.

This URI is used with the --mongo-uri option when launching mongosqld using the command line, or the mongodb.net.uri option if you are using a configuration file instead.

**Cause**

The connection times out because the --mongo-uri option has not been set correctly when launching the MongoDB Connector for BI. This option defaults to mongodb://localhost:27017 which would only work if the MongoDB database server is running on the same machine as the BI Connector (and the port number is correct as well).

Answer (score 0):

install mongodb ,
install mongodb connector odbc ,
install  mongodb bi connector :https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/bi-connector/releases/archive,
after this : go to :
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Connector for BI\2.14\bin , open mongosqld.exe,
Go to “Administrative Tools” and select “ODBC Data Sources” corresponding to your system,
Select “System DSN” and click “Add..”,
choose mongodb odbc ansi driver,
choose the name of the data source, TCP/IP server : localhost & port : see in mongosqld.exe and name of database,
test --> ok ,
go to power bi select “Get Data",
Click on the “ODBC” and then “Connect”,
In the ODBC panel, select the name of your DSN and click “OK”,
In the navigator panel, select your database and click “Load”.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5Y1B.jpg)